# Ubuntu freeze for 1 second every minute then resumes

Tags: 13.04, freeze

this is my first question here in the forum.

I'm quite ignorant on Linux overall, I am doing my first steps now.
I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my computer that is a Samsung notebook, I7, 8gb Ram, and Intel sandybridge mobile video device

What is happening is that about every minute the whole system freeze for half a second, then it resumes to normal. An interesting details is that if I am playing music, the music continues to play normally even while everything else is freeze.

The installation is new, I have only installed Heroku, Git and Emacs as far as I recall.
I have looked for similar posts and executed several steps, but did not work. In other cases I did not had the knowledge to follow the steps.

I have no clue where to start troubleshooting, can you please guys help me?

Thank you.

Comment: I have a laptop bought in 2006 that has this issue. It does not matter what kernel version, file system or Linux distribution I use, it always hangs every few seconds like you describe. It does not happen with Windows! It looks like something related to HD controler or IO. In my case, the HD is very slow (40000 RPM) and I guess that is part of the problem. Do you know the speed of your HD? If not, please paste the output of this command: sudo cat /proc/scsi/scsi

Comment: I believe mine is 5400. Here is the output of the command:
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: ATA      Model: ST1000LM024 HN-M Rev: 2AR1
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: TSSTcorp Model: DVDWBD TS-LB23D  Rev: SC02
  Type:   CD-ROM                           ANSI  SCSI revision: 05

And is exactly like you mentioned, it does not happen on Windows.

Comment: Yes, your drive is 5400 rpm. I also found someone complaining about the speed of that drive: http://windowsforum.com/threads/extremely-high-access-seek-time-for-hard-disk.85149/ There are three things you can try: 1- Try a live USB pen and see if that happens; 2- Try Ubuntu 32bit; 3- Try a different drive like an SSD, but don't waste money on a new drive. Try a spare one first. I don't have that issue when running Linux from USB pen. When running from HD, I hear the disk doing something when the system hangs, so I'm sure that in my case it's the HD or controller.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try from a Pendrive and will let you know.

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what the reason was, but after update to 13.10 the behavior stopped.