# Ubuntu 14.04.1 hangs every minute

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, iowait

Every minute I get a second or so of minor lag.  So far I know the following:

- It happens every minute around `:00` seconds
- It only affects video, not audio
- I get a spike of iowait and disk write every time it happens
- Using iotop, the culprit appears to be nautilus
- There are no jobs in `/etc/cron.d/` set to go every minute
- Nautilus does not have to have a window open for this to happen

I have a Dell Studio 1558 with an Intel i3 330M (Ironlake) and integrated Intel HD Graphics.  I'm using whatever driver is included in Ubuntu by default, specifically i915 according to `lspci -k`.

I am not absolutely certain that that problem is nautilus, but I don't know where to go from here.  Any answers or further debugging suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. Although my question seems to be a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355633/ubuntu-freeze-for-1-second-every-minute-then-resumes), no answers were ever given in that thread, and the asker closed it because updating to 13.10 fixed the problem for him/her.

Comment: I think it is your graphic driver issue. Try to find some drivers for linux and let me know. What is your lappy by the way?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I edited the original post with hardware information.  However, according to launchpad, the "xserver-xorg-video-intel" package hasn't been changed for Trusty since February, and I think that's the one that has my driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have `variety` installed, which is a wallpaper switcher. One of the options in the preferences was to have a large digital clock in the lower right corner of the desktop. Disabling this feature fixed my problem.

The iowait I was getting every minute must have been variety opening the wallpaper file and writing the new clock to it. The reason `iowait` showed the culprit to be `nautilus` is because nautilus manages the desktop and wallpaper in Ubuntu.